# How to create multiple CacheErrorHandler for multiple CacheManager?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, ehcache

I am developing a SpringBoot Microservice that is configured to use 2 cache managers, EhCache and RedisCache and i am trying to implement CacheErrorHandler to handle cache error separately.

According to [reference](https://dzone.com/articles/safeguard-spring-app-from-cache-failure), it seems like i can only define one CacheErrorHandler that handle all type of cache.

May i know is there a way to implement different CacheErrorHandler for different cache manager?

Redis Cache Manager Bean Configuration:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConditionalOnBean(CustomCacheProperties.class)
public CacheManager redisCacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory, CustomCacheProperties customCacheProperties) {
    return RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig())
            .withInitialCacheConfigurations(customCacheProperties.getInitialCacheConfigurations())
            .build();
}
```

EhCache Cache Manager Bean Configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "ehcache")
public CacheManager ehcacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
}
```

reference: https://dzone.com/articles/safeguard-spring-app-from-cache-failure

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it came up when I googled the same problem, so thought I would give an answer anyways.

As far as I know, there's no way of registering multiple error handlers, but you can differentiate error handling based on the type of the cache, like so:

```
@Override
public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
    if (cache instanceof Ehcache) {
        // ... handle EhCache failure
    } else if (cache instanceof RedisCache) {
        // ... handle Redis failure
    } else {
        // ... fallback
    }
}
```

You'll need to check the cache managers you use for the actual type of the caches they create.

You could also create proper beans implementing CacheErrorHandler, inject them into the error handler registered with Spring, and just delegate from there, to properly separate the logic.